# SQL Pivot command output

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a requirement in which after Pivot, I don’t want the aggregated value, instead I need ‘Y’. For Null values it should be ‘N’. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: show us the example and/or code.

Comment: You'll need to share far more details for us to help you here. As it is, this question will be closed as "Not a real question"

Answer (score 3):

You provided absolutely no details about your current table structure or data but you can use a `Y/N` flag in your `pivot`.  Here is a sample solution:

```
select employeename,
  isnull(hr, 'N') HR,
  isnull(IT, 'N') IT
from
(
  select e.name EmployeeName,
    d.name DeptName,
    'Y' flag
  from employee e
  left join dept_employee de
    on e.id = de.e_id
  left join dept d
    on de.d_id = d.id
) src
pivot
(
  max(flag)
  for deptname in (HR, IT)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e11d/3)